# How to paste into Wordpress editor without changing existing formatting in editor?

Tags: editor, wysiwyg, text

When you paste text into the default WP editor, say, right into the middle of existing text, the editor does not infer that you want to maintain the existing font-size and style in the document.

Instead, it uses the font styles from wherever the text was copied from. And you have to type the text over again or mess around with the html.

How do you bypass this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the **Paste as Text** button, or paste into the **Text** tab instead of the **Visual** tab.

Comment: Ah that's exactly what I was looking for. So it's not a design flaw it's a switch.